# PHP Socket Android система сообщений. Как это устроено?

Tags: php, сокет, архитектура, websocket

Хочу реализовать систему обмена сообщений на клиентских Android приложениях через PHP сервер. Опыта нет, только теоретические данные.

Архитектура вырисовывается примерно такая:

VPS или аренда сервера (Dedicated). Файловое хранилище (изображения пользователей), БД и вся логика на одном сервере. Огромных нагрузок не планируется.

Интересует вопрос организации real-time переписки. Как я понял, для этой задачи подходят только socket`ы, т.к. писать логику на клиенте, что бы к примеру каждую секунду проверял наличие новых сообщений, не является хорошим решением.

Верно ли что открыв 1 (или если будет эффективнее 2-5-10 сокетов), они смогут обрабатывать 100-1000 пользователей? Нет необходимости открывать новый сокет для каждого пользователя?

Безопасно/целесообразно реализовывать логику сокетов на одном сервере с файлами и БД?

P.S. Если нужна дополнительная информация, прошу указать в комментариях.